# How to develop an Android application without Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I've installed and set up Java JDK 17 as well as Android SDK (the manual way) on my Ubuntu 22.04.
From there, is it possible to develop an Android application in Java WITHOUT Android Studio ?
Developing through the command line or through a light IDE is fine by me, but there are very few guidance and information out there.
Thanks to enlighten me.

Comment: The Android SDK documentation has https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline and https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line among other pages on this.

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this? Modern IDEs offer so many performance benefits for developers (basically doing a ton of the work for you, and catching lots of errors immediately during development)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can! You'll need to type an awful lot of stuff though, that Android Studio does for you automatically:

You'll need to create gradle files to build your project, you'll need to create an Android manifest to describe your Android components and your app (permissions, themes, target SDK, etc.).

You'll need to create the code files containing your Android components (`Activity`, `Fragment`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, etc.). You'll need to create all your UI definition files in XML (layouts and other resources).

Then you can use gradle on the command line to run all the necessary preprocessors, code generators, compilers, linkers, resource builders and package builders to give you an APK which you can then install on your device for testing. And you can debug by writing lots of stuff to the logs and using `adb` commands to get the logcat off the device to see the log messages, exceptions and stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be possible and I've long wanted to find a way to do this. Only I'd also like to avoid Java and the SDK.

Here's one guide: https://www.revelo.com/blog/how-to-build-an-android-development-environment-without-android-studio

Guide from Debian for their packaged tools: https://wiki.debian.org/AndroidTools

It's hard to pick what the critical enabling step there is, though and what exactly is the original question.